# как отменить все действия программы, если пользователь оборвал ее исполнение

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, chat

мне нужно сделать так, что бы при нажатии ctrl+c программа отменяла все изменения, которые сама и вносила.
Например, вот часть программы, которая записывает в 1-ый указанный файл все остальные (при условии, что в списке может оказаться и он сам) через временный файл в /tmp.

```
   f1="$1"
   shift
   f2=mktemp
       cat "${@}" >> $f2 
       mv $f2 $f1
   trap kill "$$" 2
```

Но эта программа не удаляет временный файл.
Как его удалить?

PS да, есть команда cut, но при попадании f1 в списке для копирования в f1, программа запускает вечный двигатель, это не подходит.

Comment: Все команды в описанном сценарии выполняются на лету, скрипт можно адаптировать написав ему план отката, без него откат выполнятся не будет. Опишите в начале скрипта функцию отката `rollback() { комманды для отката; }` после укажите trap вызов функции `trap rollback 2`. В вашем примере программа trap не сработает во время cat и mv, так как устанавливается позже

Comment: И в дополнение, если хотите изучить тему глубже `man atexit`.

Comment: @0andriy, но в Bash ведь нет `atexit`?

Comment: @eanmos, а кто говорил про bash? Это для понимания более низкого уровня, чем bash.

Comment: @0andriy, ну вопрос как бы про Bash. Тем более, `atexit` не ловит Ctr+C (`SIGINT`) — тут скорее `signal`.